# Magento 2 setup:static-content:deploy symlinks

Tags: magento2, static-content, deploy, deployment

When removing all the `pub/static` files in Magento 2 and opening the homepage, the files are generated as symlinks. When using the command `setup:static-content:deploy` the files are copied, even after setting the deploy mode to developer with the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`. How can I get the static generated as symlinks from terminal, as in the browser it takes much more longer?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve this by adding this node in app/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="assetPublisher" xsi:type="object">developerPublisher</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

For magento 2.2 code will be

```
 <type name="Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="assetPublisher" xsi:type="object">developerPublisher</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Note that this approach means static files will *always* be deployed as symlinks, even in production.

Comment: I always though that this didn't work until I cleared out the var/view_preprocessed before deploying static content and now it definitely does work.